# Is There a GUI for Showing Game Services Matches?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I can only imagine there must be a way for me to invoke some kind of GUI that will show all the matches a player has going on, whose turn it is, who they're playing etc. Is there such a GUI call for Google Play Game Services or do I really need to work this all out manually by loading matches and created my own GUI from the data? It's proving to be a lot of work and I feel like it just HAS to be wasted effort. Game Center has it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Developing a Turn-based Multiplayer Game in Android found in the Google Play Game Services docs.

> Once a player has signed in to your game, the player may receive invitations to join a turn-based match created by another player. To save coding time and provide users with a consistent UI for responding to match invitations across applications, you can use the default match inbox UI provided by the SDK. To launch the default match inbox UI, call getInboxIntent() to get an Intent; then call startActivityForResult() and pass in that Intent.

It appears there is a built in GUI. I don't have an app to try it out but you can get more information [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#selecting_players_with_the_default_user_interface) I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! It turns out that's not only for Invitations. It works for existing matches as well.